# bash testing to see if a script is being run in a certain directory with aliases and not using string matching

Tags: bash, directory

I have a bash script I am writing for a public code and I want to ensure that the user is not running the script directly in the git repository (or sub-directory thereof).  I have an environmental variable CODELIB that points to the repository location and I was testing for string matching in the following way, with wildcards to catch subdirectories:

```
if [[ `pwd` == *${CODELIB}* ]]; then
  echo "error: do not run in your git repository " $CODELIB
  exit 1
fi
```

This works fine in most circumstances, but is sometimes caught out if the user has their code in a subdirectory of $HOME, as my employer using AFS, and there seems to be use of aliases such that for some users the home is mounted such that

```
cd $HOME
pwd
```

gives this

```
/afs/xyz.it/home/t/user/
```

instead of this

```
/afs/xyz/home/t/user/
```

As the variable CODELIB points to

```
/afs/xyz/home/t/user/code_location
```

my test fails in this case.  I was therefore wondering if there were an inbuilt function in bash that could more robustly test if a directory is a subdirectory of another without resorting to string matching.

The solutions I found here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6435/how-to-check-if-pwd-is-a-subdirectory-of-a-given-path were all based on string matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `realpath` on both directories.

```
if [[ "$(realpath "$(pwd)")"/ == "$(realpath "${CODELIB}")"/* ]]; then
```

If `realpath` is not available but perl is:

```
realpath(){
    perl -MCwd -e 'print Cwd::realpath($ARGV[0])' "$1"
}
```

Comment: hi again, I just found a case where the first solution fails...  if my git directory is something like /home/code  and I have another parallel directory /home/code_morestuff and I run from there, it detects one being in code.  I tried to put a / after the CODELIB but that didn't seem to help.  For the moment I changed my error message to "don't run in your git library location, (or anything that is named remotely like it!!!)" :-D

Comment: see if amended version fixes that

Comment: Ah yes, that fixes it! Silly me, I had put the / after CODELIB but forgotten to fix the pwd part - thank you so much!